# how to avoid a shared link to be open by unauthorized persons

Tags: url, video

How to avoid a shared link to be open by unauthorized persons. For example if a given user recieved a private/premium video link. I don't want that person to transfert the link and i don't want the reciever to open the video since that person are not a regular user.

Comment: What server technology are we talking about?

Comment: a youtube video for example

Comment: Are there other types of videos which should be restricted?

Comment: No i would like only the users to whom i send the link to be authorize to use it. Not any other. An i just want to use Youtube to host my content

Comment: Then you will need to ask this non-programming question on a youtube-related forum.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming, but rather youtube video privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of several ways to address this issue but none of them are 100% perfect in solving the problem. 
**Option 1** - Issue different links for your premium subscribers with a one time pass. 
 Once the user logs in to watch the video he's asked to input his OTP and the link becomes irrelevant after it is used. 
**Option 2** - Watermark the video with the name of the user who received the link and warn them not to share the link pending legal action which can be traced back to their account. 
**Option 3** - Create a private section which requires the user to sign up and monitor use. For instance, enable only one device to be logged into the service at one time. 

Do note that all options may annoy your users and sway them away from your service. It is quite difficult keeping content "safe" these days and you're basically faced with the Netflix problem. 
Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!